# Change view tab link

Tags: 7, views, theming

I created a simple view to show the node fields of a certain content type.
Now I'd like to change the path of the view tab to the view's path.

I read this question:

[Change name of a tab for a specific content type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48276/change-name-of-a-tab-for-a-specific-content-type)

and I think to implement something similar, but I don't know exactly what element change.

I know I could create a .tpl but it's easier theme with the view in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Why not create a `node--node-type--full.tpl.php` instead? No views needed.

Comment: Because the views is ready :)

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't even make sense. You can set your field displays on the 'Default' for that content type, and that template will be used to output it in whatever way you want.